# An abelian subgroup of symmetric group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, symmetric-groups

**PROBLEM:** Let $G$ be an abelian subgroup of the symmetric group $S_n$ and $p_1, . . . , p_k$ be all prime divisors of $|G|$. Prove that $n≥p_1 +···+p_k$.

**QUESTION:** How do you solve this problem. I've thought about using the Sylow theorems but I can't seem to get the final inequality.

Comment: Since every subgroup of an abelian group is normal, you know that there can only be 1 $p_i$-subgroup for each $i$, as these are in the same conjugacy class. Maybe this can help?

Comment: So we could write $G$ as the product of the Sylow p-groups, but then we only get $n\geq p_1+...+p_k-k+1$

Comment: How do I get rid of $-k+1$?

Comment: I'm studying the same subject so I'm as stuck as you. I will think about it though!

Comment: If $p$ is a prime, what does an element of $S_n$ of order $p$ look like?

Comment: I think I might have it. We know that $G$ is abelian and finite, so it is in fact cyclic. So there is an element,$g$ in $G$ with order $p_1p_2...p_k$. This element can't belong to any p-sylow subgroup because it would imply that $|g|<p_1p_2...p_k$ Similarly $g^{p_1}$ can't belong to any p-sylow subgroup and is distinct from $g$ because it has order $p_2p_3...p_k$. Iterating this process we get $k-1$ terms not contained in any of the p-sylow subgroups. Thus, $|G|>p_1+...+p_k$.

Comment: @S.S: The Klein four group is abelian and finite, but _not_ cyclic.

Comment: Okay my mistake. I should have used the fact that we can choose an element of order $p_i$ in each $p_i-sylow$ subgroup. And since the orders of each element is relatively prime the product of the elements has order $p_1p_2...p_k$.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I am assuming these are the distinct prime divisors of $|G|$. In that case $G$ has an element of order $p_1p_2\cdots p_k$ since it is abelian. The order of an element of $S_n$ is the least common multiple of the lengths of its disjoint cycles. These lengths must sum to a number less than or equal to $n$. Since the $p_i$ are prime, there must be at least one cycle length divisible by each of the primes (with some cycle lengths possibly divisible by multiple primes). Since $xy\geq x+y$ whenever $x,y\geq 2$, the smallest possible sum of the lengths of the cycles in the element with this order is $p_1+p_2+\cdots+p_k\leq n$.

Comment: Wow, that was pretty sweet. Using abelians are clt was rather ingenious.

Comment: @Matt Samuel: "Since the $p_i$ are prime, there must be at least one cycle length divisible by each of the primes". Why? Why can't one cycle be divisible by some of the primes and another cycle divisible by the remaining primes...

Comment: @Joshua Not divisible by all of them, divisible by each of them. It could be any number of different cycles.

Comment: Wow,, pretty one. :))